# what is the snakemake variable name for slurm job id?

Tags: snakemake

When I run jobs on snakemake using `--profile ./slurm`, I see in standard output:

```
Submitted job 406 with external jobid '1956125'
```

in `slurm/config.yaml` I have:

```
cores: "all"
cluster: "sbatch --partition=mypartition -A myaccount  -t {resources.time_min} --mem={resources.mem_mb} -c {resources.cpus} -o slurm/logs/{jobid}.out -e slurm/logs/{jobid}.err --mail-type=FAIL --mail-user=mymail.edu --parsable"
default-resources: [cpus=1, mem_mb=2000, time_min=10080, parition=mypartition]
use-conda: true
```

This writes log files like `406.err` and what I want is `1956125.err`

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`406` is the internal `jobid` from snakemake. You want the external `jobid` from slurm.

IIRC that should be possible by using `%j` instead of `{jobid}`:

```py
cluster: "sbatch --partition=mypartition -A myaccount  -t {resources.time_min} --mem={resources.mem_mb} -c {resources.cpus} -o slurm/logs/%j.out -e slurm/logs/%j.err --mail-type=FAIL --mail-user=mymail.edu --parsable"
```

Let us know if it works.